# Can't run local Sonar analysis in Eclipse: Sonar version 3.4 is required to perform local analysis

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm running Sonar both on Jenkins and local Eclipse. Recently I've updated Sonar plugin for Eclipse and since then I keep on getting the upper mentioned error. I've updated the plugin on Jenkins as well, but it did not fix the issue. I can connect to server from Eclipse and see Sonar reports there, but local analysis won't start. How can this be fixed? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to a Sonar server which version is less than 3.4.

If you upgrade your Sonar server to lastest version (3.4.1), everything will be back to normal.

Comment: I've updated both local and server plugins to the latest version.

Comment: Also which version of Eclipse are you using? Last version of Sonar Eclipse (3.0) is compatible with Eclipse 3.7+ only. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar+in+Eclipse

Comment: Eclipse is 4.2 and it supports latest Sonar, as displayed on the page you gave me link to. Strange thing is that it all worked before I updated Sonar on my local machine..

Comment: You should provide more details, otherwise it's hard to help you more. :-(

Comment: Please tell me what kind of details do I need to provide.

Comment: First, a copy of the log output.

Comment: "Sonar version 3.4 is required to perform local analysis." - this is all I'm getting inside an error dialog, which pops up when I try to run Local analysis.

Comment: Well, this clearly means that you're trying to connect to a version of Sonar < 3.4. Check your settings again, remove Sonar nature and add it again once you're sure that you connect to a 3.4 Sonar server.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't attentive enough, I've updated the Eclipse Sonar plugin, the Jenkins Sonar plugin, but I didn't update the Sonar itself. Thanks for your help, Fabrice!